# Heroku - Multiple dynos

Tags: heroku

my application was suffering from a lack of RAM. I decided to add another web dyno type (standard-2x). I expected to have 2GB RAM (2x x 1GB) but still in metrics I see only Mem Quote equals 1024 MB. Why? How can I see the difference in metrics while adding the next dynos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku dyno standard 2x only offers 1GB ram and 2x cpu share, you can check  [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types)

Also if you will add multiple dyno then they will act like substitute means adding 2 dynos will not double the actual memory.Please use next plan (performance -m) which provide 2.5 GB ram